# discover meteor commit 9-5-4 showing no content

Tags: meteor

Going through the Discover Meteor book and when I get to the 9.5 sidebar and do those coding tasks I end up with no content being shown at all. All I get is a gear spinning and nothing ever loads.

Here's the error I'm getting in the console:
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Suggestions?

Sorry, don't have enough rep to post screenshot. If you check github for the 9-5-4 commit you will see my screenshot